How to diagnose an 28x slowdown in containerized vs host python+numpy execution
I'm doing some number-crunching in a docker container. On an 8 cpu machine the dockerized execution is around 28x slower than the host?
I've examined:

warm-up costs: I've tried running the test on the second execution in the same process (below the warmup costs appear negligble anyway)
numpy optimization options:  import numpy ; numpy.show_config() shows identical result in the container and the host
cpus: os.cpu_count reports the same in the container as the host.
file IO: on the second run, there is no file IO. (The first run loads data, the second had the data cached in memory)
blas vs openblas installed
python version (both use python 3.10)
numpy version  (1.22.4 for both)
fastdtw version (both same)

The program uses fastdtw which uses numpy internally. Here is a minimal driver:
#fdtw.py
# Runs in 1s on host
# Runs in 28s in Docker
import numpy as np
from fastdtw import fastdtw
import time

a = np.sin(np.arange(1000))
b = np.cos(np.arange(3000))

t = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    fastdtw(a,b)
print(time.time()-t)


The numpy setup and test execution in Docker. A lot of the expensive calls are implement in cython (https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw/tree/master/fastdtw). Some not being compiled and optimized in the Docker case? How?
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install nano build-essential software-properties-common libpng-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libopenblas-dev libopenblas64-0-openmp

RUN apt-get -y install gfortran liblapack3 liblapack-dev

#    libatlas-base-dev libatlas-base-dev
#     libblas3  libblas-dev

RUN pip3 install numpy==1.22.4 fastdtw

COPY /server /

RUN python -c 'import numpy ; print(numpy.__version__)'
RUN python -c 'import numpy ; numpy.show_config()'

RUN python -m cProfile  -s cumtime /server/fdtw.py > log.txt
RUN cat log.txt | head -500

RUN exit 1

The docker profile output:
#12 [ 8/36] RUN python -c 'import numpy ; print(numpy.__version__)'
#12 0.427 1.22.4
#12 DONE 0.5s

#13 [ 9/36] RUN python -c 'import numpy ; numpy.show_config()'
#13 0.611 openblas64__info:
#13 0.611     libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
#13 0.611     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611     language = c
#13 0.611     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
#13 0.611     runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611 blas_ilp64_opt_info:
#13 0.611     libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
#13 0.611     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611     language = c
#13 0.611     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
#13 0.611     runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611 openblas64__lapack_info:
#13 0.611     libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
#13 0.611     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611     language = c
#13 0.611     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
#13 0.611     runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611 lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
#13 0.611     libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
#13 0.611     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611     language = c
#13 0.611     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
#13 0.611     runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
#13 0.611 Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
#13 0.611     baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
#13 0.611     found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
#13 0.611     not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
#13 DONE 0.7s

#14 [10/36] RUN python -m cProfile  -s cumtime /server/fdtw.py > log.txt
#14 DONE 28.5s



#15 [11/36] RUN cat log.txt | head -500
#15 0.320 27.874674558639526
#15 0.320          46359783 function calls (46356877 primitive calls) in 28.046 seconds
#15 0.320 
#15 0.320    Ordered by: cumulative time
#15 0.320 
#15 0.320    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#15 0.320     112/1    0.000    0.000   28.046   28.046 {built-in method builtins.exec}
#15 0.320         1    0.010    0.010   28.046   28.046 fdtw.py:1(<module>)
#15 0.320       100    0.063    0.001   27.865    0.279 fastdtw.py:15(fastdtw)
#15 0.320  1000/100    0.899    0.001   27.800    0.278 fastdtw.py:64(__fastdtw)
#15 0.320      1000    9.697    0.010   18.775    0.019 fastdtw.py:133(__dtw)
#15 0.320       900    5.837    0.006    7.933    0.009 fastdtw.py:157(__expand_window)
#15 0.320   4349147    4.383    0.000    5.852    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
#15 0.320   4348100    1.212    0.000    1.711    0.000 fastdtw.py:56(__difference)
#15 0.320  13044300    1.469    0.000    1.469    0.000 fastdtw.py:143(<lambda>)
#15 0.320   4349100    1.176    0.000    1.176    0.000 fastdtw.py:137(<genexpr>)
#15 0.320   7089966    0.923    0.000    0.923    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
#15 0.320   2991000    0.849    0.000    0.849    0.000 fastdtw.py:160(<genexpr>)
#15 0.320   4348196    0.499    0.000    0.499    0.000 {built-in method builtins.abs}
#15 0.320        14    0.001    0.000    0.373    0.027 __init__.py:1(<module>)
#15 0.320   4949989    0.372    0.000    0.372    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
#15 0.320    798400    0.290    0.000    0.290    0.000 fastdtw.py:138(<lambda>)
#15 0.320      1800    0.003    0.000    0.191    0.000 fastdtw.py:153(__reduce_by_half)
#15 0.320      1800    0.188    0.000    0.188    0.000 fastdtw.py:154(<listcomp>)
... minor costs follow ...


The same tests on the host:
$ python -c 'import numpy ; print(numpy.__version__)'
1.22.4
$ python -c 'import numpy ; numpy.show_config()'
openblas64__info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas64__lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL


$ python -m cProfile  -s cumtime fdtw.py > log.txt
$ cat log.txt | head -500
0.1275956630706787
         90773 function calls (88792 primitive calls) in 0.286 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       14    0.001    0.000    0.336    0.024 __init__.py:1(<module>)
    111/1    0.000    0.000    0.286    0.286 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.006    0.006    0.286    0.286 fdtw.py:1(<module>)
    151/2    0.001    0.000    0.159    0.079 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1022(_find_and_load)
    151/2    0.001    0.000    0.159    0.079 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:987(_find_and_load_unlocked)
    139/2    0.001    0.000    0.158    0.079 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:664(_load_unlocked)
    110/2    0.000    0.000    0.158    0.079 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:877(exec_module)
    217/2    0.000    0.000    0.158    0.079 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:233(_call_with_frames_removed)
   180/16    0.001    0.000    0.154    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1053(_handle_fromlist)
    362/8    0.001    0.000    0.153    0.019 {built-in method builtins.__import__}
      100    0.117    0.001    0.122    0.001 {fastdtw._fastdtw.fastdtw}
      110    0.001    0.000    0.041    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:950(get_code)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.029    0.029 multiarray.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.028    0.028 numeric.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.028    0.028 overrides.py:1(<module>)
      316    0.002    0.000    0.022    0.000 overrides.py:170(decorator)
      110    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:670(_compile_bytecode)
      110    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
  139/136    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:564(module_from_spec)
      148    0.001    0.000    0.018    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:921(_find_spec)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.008 shape_base.py:1(<module>)
      286    0.001    0.000    0.017    0.000 overrides.py:88(verify_matching_signatures)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.016 py3k.py:1(<module>)
      110    0.010    0.000    0.016    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1070(get_data)
      136    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1431(find_spec)
      136    0.001    0.000    0.015    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1399(_get_spec)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 fromnumeric.py:1(<module>)
      622    0.001    0.000    0.015    0.000 _inspect.py:96(getargspec)
       17    0.000    0.000    0.014    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1174(create_module)
       17    0.011    0.001    0.014    0.001 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
      289    0.003    0.000    0.013    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1536(find_spec)
      151    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:169(__enter__)
      454    0.001    0.000    0.012    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:179(_get_module_lock)
      622    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 _inspect.py:26(isfunction)
      150    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:71(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.010    0.010 _add_newdocs_scalars.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.010    0.010 _pickle.py:1(<module>)
      150    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.000 re.py:288(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.009 platform.py:1(<module>)
    17/12    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1182(exec_module)
    17/12    0.003    0.000    0.009    0.001 {built-in method _imp.exec_dynamic}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.008 pathlib.py:1(<module>)
       28    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.000 sre_compile.py:783(compile)
       25    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.000 re.py:249(compile)
  219/218    0.004    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 index_tricks.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.005 _add_newdocs.py:1(<module>)
      313    0.001    0.000    0.005    0.000 function_base.py:475(add_newdoc)
       28    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 sre_parse.py:944(parse)
     1501    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:126(_path_join)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 secrets.py:1(<module>)
      139    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:492(_init_module_attrs)
    77/28    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 sre_parse.py:436(_parse_sub)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 numerictypes.py:1(<module>)
    82/30    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 sre_parse.py:494(_parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 pickle.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 subprocess.py:1(<module>)
      596    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:140(_path_stat)
     2000    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 numerictypes.py:356(issubdtype)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 ntpath.py:1(<module>)
      596    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method posix.stat}
       28    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 sre_compile.py:622(_code)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 version.py:1(<module>)
      326    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 functools.py:35(update_wrapper)
      220    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:380(cache_from_source)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 defmatrix.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 defchararray.py:1(<module>)
      303    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:216(_lock_unlock_module)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.001 _version.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 hmac.py:1(<module>)
... minor costs follow



Using perf could help to track the problem assuming you have the required rights (and the paranoid file configured properly as mentioned in perf). More information about the target system/environment would help a lot, starting by the CPU reference, the Numpy+CPython version on both instances, and the kind of Numpy function used (eg. BLAS/Lapack ones or classical ones).

Thanks. OK - some of the optimizations were not installed on closer inspection. (I wasn't reading the output correctly). But even after installing them, there's not a huge speedup (a 6x difference vs 8x). I added numpy.show_config above.
Docker:  py 3.11, numpy 1.26.4  | Host is py 3.10, 1.22.4.

I'll have a look into profiling also.

Have you tried using the same versions of numpy and Python in both environments?

Does this happen with any numpy code? What about pure Python code?

Check you use OpenBLAS in both cases. The installed CBlas and Atlas libraries are AFAIK not efficient BLAS. OpenBLAS, MKL and BLIS are example of fast BLAS (OpenBLAS is the default free/open-source one). You can check the BLAS performance using a simple A @ B on big 2D arrays A and B.

@JérômeRichard I tried replacing blas/blas-dev with openblas, making both use the the same numpy and python version - does not resolve it.
I've updated the question with profiling information - in Docker vs the host. Perhaps you see something? Yes numpy calls are more expensive. They are mostly calls from within a cython extension library, if that makes a difference.

It looks like the two just do not call the same functions. I mean there is no Numpy or linalg function call in the second case, and the path taken in fastdtw also seems different. Are you sure the input and the code is exactly the same in both cases? It is hard without the code nor more advanced profiling information to help you.

Yes -- that a difference with numpy or a dependency, I think, not my driver. The same program is run in both cases, using the same input files and they produces the same correct output. I'll see if I can produce a more trivial driver.

I've updated the question with a minimal driver. (Thanks to the perf output -- thanks).
Think looks worse now - a 28x difference in docker vs the host.

One thing that stick out: {built-in method builtins.min} is called 1047 times on the host and 4349147 times in docker. I assume this is python min, not native code or numpy min, and its a mistake if fastdtw is using it so much. Why would the fastdtw library by using python min in docker, but not the host?
I don't understand how the cython code is compiled and optimized here.

FastDTW contains both a fast path implemented in Cython, and a slow path implemented in Python. It tries the fast path first, and if it gets an ImportError, it falls back to the slow path. You are probably hitting the fast path in the host, and the slow path in the container.
Some evidence for this idea:

The functions called in both are completely different. In the fast one, about a quarter of the functions in the trace are NumPy related. In the slow one, NumPy doesn't appear at all.
builtins.min() appears in the slow profile. While both the fast path and slow path use min(), Cython compiles this into C code which makes no use of the Python min(). Therefore, the slower profile must be using the slow path in FastDTW.

Source code where this feature is implemented:

See here for the code which implements the fallback.
See here for the fast path.
See here for the slow path.

You can use the following code to check this:
import inspect
import fastdtw
fastdtw.dtw
inspect.getfile(fastdtw.dtw)

Output, slow path:
Python 3.10.10 (main, Jun 25 2023, 11:16:46) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> import fastdtw
>>> fastdtw.dtw
<function dtw at 0x10f9441f0>
>>> inspect.getfile(fastdtw.dtw)
'/Users/nick/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastdtw/fastdtw.py'

Output, fast path:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> import fastdtw
>>> fastdtw.dtw
<built-in function dtw>
>>> inspect.getfile(fastdtw.dtw)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 797, in getfile
    raise TypeError('module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or '
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method

Timing of slow path: 16.39020 seconds
Timing of fast path: 0.09339 seconds
(Note: slow path and fast path benchmark are run on different hardware.)

Thanks for the detailed explanation. But, I guess, why does the Docker container go down this other route.

Actually, I guess I can debug the exception in the Docker container. Will try that.

from ._fastdtw import fastdtw, dtw
in Docker produces
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastdtw._fastdtw'.
And  ls /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastdtw/ shows only __init__.py  __pycache__  fastdtw.py  ... no _fastdtw.
But my host only, I also have _fastdtw.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, Both are using fastdtw==0.3.4. Why the difference?

pip3 install cython solves this. sigh
Thanks for you help!
